# HttpClient SendAsync thread call back dies before parsing response

Tags: asynchronous, java-metro-framework, dotnet-httpclient

I am testing out the httpClient sendAsync method. Synchrnous call it works fine. But, when I try to do asynchronous http
requests, the task terminated before I process the message. Any body encountered with this issue?

This synchronous call works

```
HttpRequestMessage httprequest = new HttpRequestMessage(httpmethod, "http://www.google.ca");
var result =   _httpClient.SendAsync(httprequest, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, cancellationToken);
HttpResponseMessage response = result.Result;
```

But the Asynchrnous call doesn't work. The thread dies when I try to parse the response.

```
HttpRequestMessage httprequest = new HttpRequestMessage(httpmethod, "http://www.google.ca");
var result =   await _httpClient.SendAsync(httprequest, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, cancellationToken);
HttpResponseMessage response = result;
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "the thread dies"? Do you see an exception, or does the application exit?

Comment: It exited the application with following message in the output windows. [3408] vstest.executionengine.appcontainer.x86.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0). And the scenario only exists in the unit test. In a sample app it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using VS11 Beta, then make sure your unit test returns `Task`, not `void`.

If you're using VS2010 or VS11 Dev Preview, then you can use my [Async Unit Tests](http://asyncunittests.codeplex.com/) project.

Full details are [on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-unit-tests-part-1-wrong-way.html), but it boils down to this:

- `async` will return when it has to asynchronously wait.
- In a unit test, it's returning to the test runner, which sees the test complete.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Yes it works fine after I changed the unit test to return Task.